# Typescript function return type based on optional arguments

Tags: typescript

How can bad types be resolved?

[TS sandbox.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBoB4AqA+ZBvAWAChlTk4AjBALk2IF9jiATCBAGzihRgFcQEYYAHsQyVhAAOAGWEIA1ugDyFAFbIIAD0ghmAZ2QAlNsKjN0esFFABzADTkQAT2x3sACmFrqyFaoCUPhh+2ADcLGyc3Mh8AkKi4hBSsgrKahraELoGxgim5pbWIPaOLm6e3r5qDsKS8SB6Pnj0gWhpqmERHFw8-IIiYhIycorEpH4ZOvpGJmYWVrYOcM6uY8gAgv0JWlMGAEQw3BAAXhB7yAA+yHt6EHDs51d7ktwAbllgAKKZDQN6e3Y1ko6n9JllpnhyFsQAB+HyberIRhEDxeVQ+Pw1EGiPRw3zYhqtBEDMHZZAAckOSVO5OQMLaIWQGLUTCIAHo2chhPJiHkGmBkJpkABeRLJEbuZr+ZAcjKSNgCjDNbC8nECzQAJhFYuGCkl9AcUplnK08sEbWVrNlICSzGQYGEyAoPGAmggzFV-MFAGZtUMUvJ9YbEPUfJSjjSWsa5QqLfQVUQ+ZZBQAWP1JXWB5rB6Fh273clR2Wm2N+T3JzQAVnT4r12fwIYGYZeEHe4G+Oj0f0L0uLmjNAr8QA)

```
interface X<T> {
    abc:T
}

declare function deepLock<Obj extends Record<string, any>,>(obj: Obj): X<Obj>;
declare function deepLock<Obj extends Record<string, any>,>(obj: Obj, options: {}): X<Obj>;
declare function deepLock<
  Obj extends Record<string, any>,
  Action extends "freeze" | "seal" | "preventExtensions",
  Options extends { action?: Action }
>(obj: Obj, options?: Options): Action extends 'freeze' ? X<Obj> : Obj

// ok
const x = deepLock({}) // expect X<{}>
const x2 = deepLock({}, {}) // expect X<{}>

// need to be fixed
const x3 = deepLock({}, {action: 'freeze'}) // expect X<{}>
const x4 = deepLock({}, {action: 'seal'}) // expect Obj
const x5 = deepLock({}, {action: 'preventExtensions'}) // expect Obj
```

Comment: the TS sandbox is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just need to adjust your function definition very slightly to:

```js
declare function deepLock<
  Obj extends Record<string, any>,
  Action extends "seal" | "preventExtensions" | "freeze",
>(obj: Obj, options?: { action?: Action }): 'freeze' extends Action ? X<Obj> : Obj;
```

The problem you are facing is that `Action` is extending `"seal" | "preventExtensions" | "freeze"` and so by definition `Action extends "freeze"` will always be true as it always extends that.

So in order to correctly narrow the types you have to do `"freeze" extends Action` which will only ever be true for one of the three possibilities for Action.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=45&pln=8&pc=84#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBoB4AqA+ZBvAKGWOTgCMEAuTAgXwIIBMIEAbOKFGAVxATGAB7EMmYQADgBlBCANboiyAPJkAVsggAPSCEYBnZACUWgqI3R6wUUAHMANKRABPbHcUBBfkJFad+5ABEehBwrAHIAD6B4pwAbhDgAKLaCXreeuFRATCcEABeEAFu2AAUgmqUymoOguICwnoA-JV4pF7Czcie9SK0AJSVAOQ5EPkQgxopugbd3siNaOgqqriVywDcDAD0W8iCsgQIDWDImsgAvKKjUjKyJXj9yDuT4iwnGA-Yh8enAEwXVwk0jk91oDgefSeuy0r34i0+212IFGjGQYEEyDIXGAmggjG+IEspwAzACxDcQQ9wYgekMRmNBo9njC3vDaF8joSTpoACxk67Au5U-A07xDYKhRmQ5maWEnZYEomaACs-KBt1B1PaICGMQg8SSUzSDSlUJerIVQA)

Hope that makes sense